# How to set min width of column equal to max text width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For each column I want to ensure the minimum width is equal to the length of the html in that column's elements.

If I console.log x below, I get the length of every text element. But when I set it below it gets set to 0px. If I manually input $(this).css('min-width',50), it sets every min-width to 50.

How do I set each td's min-width to its own unique text length?

```
        $('.table2excel td').each(function () {
            var x = this.innerText.length;
            $(this).css('min-width',x);
        })
```

Comment: I guess your code is working,try inspect element to see the min width

Comment: Unfortunately, as said in the post, it sets them each to 0px with the method above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a different approach:

- compute the max td with
- set this value to all tds

```js
var maxW = 0;
$('.table2excel td').each(function () {
    var x = this.innerText.length;
    if (x > maxW) {
        maxW = x;
    }
});
$('.table2excel td').css('min-width', maxW + 'px');
```

```css
td{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table2excel">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>333</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>444</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks gaetanoM but I don't want to set it globally. Each column has its own max length of text that i'd like to set the min-width to.

Comment: have you tried with: $(this).css('min-width',x + 'px');  ??